# Facebook Messenger Bot Review

Tags: facebook, bots

I submitted my bot for review today.

Unfortunately, Facebook doesn't seem to be able to access the bot as it doesn't reply to the test messages.

However, when I promote a friend to "Tester" in the Developers app, the bot works just fine.

Do you guys have any idea on why the bot doesn't answer to facebook tests ?

Thanks

Comment: Ran into exactly the same thing today...I posted this before finding your message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528084/my-facebook-messenger-bot-is-completed-but-isnt-visible-to-be-approved

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you should make sure before posting your Messenger Bot for review, is **if your page**, the bot is connected with, **is published**.

If the Facebook Page isn't published then Facebook's reviewers can't access your bot.

Answer (score 0):

As [Christos Panagiotakopoulos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6141173/christos-panagiotakopoulos) mentioned, Facebook requires that the page associated with the bot is published.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review

I've experienced this as well. Unfortunately the instructions were not listed when making the review request, which can be confusing for new users.