# My Facebook Messenger Bot is completed, but isn't visible to be approved

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-apps, messenger, facebook-app-requests

We built a Facebook Messenger bot that works perfectly. The bot is only available to developers and testers and can't be made public until it's approved.  We submitted it for approval but the approval person obviously didn't have access to the bot because they typed in the commands and got no reply (which is expected if they're not a developer or tester).  The screenshot they showed also didn't have the "get started" at the beginning, which is another clue that they didn't have access)

How do I give Facebook app reviewers access to my bot so they can see it working?  I'm obviously missing a step that's not obvious.

Comment: Of course the reviewers have accounts that are not affected by these restrictions ... much more likely that something else went wrong on your end.

Comment: I agree, I assumed that they should have no restrictions...but this bot has been tested extensively.  I can see in their screenshot that they just dont have access since they dont have the "Get Started" prompt that starts any messenger session.

Comment: And, I just found someone else with the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443168/facebook-messenger-bot-review

Comment: Try asking here https://m.facebook.com/?_rdr#!/groups/283148615350518 big facebook bot group

Comment: It turns out that the FB people just didn't know what they were doing, apparently.  We submitted again with no changes and it was then approved.  No idea what's up with that but apparently there's no secret I was missing.